# Grid overlay on an annulus. Move n squares to create a sector that is closest to the area of the original.

Tags: geometry, circles

I want to create an image in photoshop, and need to break an annulus, pictured below, into smaller segments. I can use other methods to find the solution, but I'm interested to see how mathematicians would handle it.

Here is the image: [image]
As you can see, there is a grid overlay on the annulus. I would like to know how you would calculate, using this squares on the grid overlay, the number of squares you need to move round in order to create sections of roughly equal size.

Here is what the final output would look like (approximately)[image]

I'm interested in verbose answers as well as formulaic ones

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by moving squares. Where do they go from their original position?

Comment: I don't literally mean move squares - I mean what pattern would you have to follow to know when to draw a line to create a sector

Comment: What do you mean by a pattern? What sort of pattern are you hoping to get?